# Jest fails when trying to find type definition in node_modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, babeljs

I'm working on a back-end powered by Node, using Babel and Typescript, and Jest (with ts-jest) for testing.

Everything worked great until 2 days ago, my testing is not working anymore, instead I get
`error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for [module name]`

This error happens for every module in my **node_modules** folder which doesn't have a **.d.ts** file in it. 
Here are the first few lines of the error for you to see :

```
FAIL  src/entity/OfferPool.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeScript diagnostics (customize using `[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.diagnostics` option):
    error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '.bin'.
    error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '.cache'.
    error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '@babel'.
    error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '@types'.
    error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'abab'.
    error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'abbrev'.
    error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'accepts'.
    error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'acorn'.
    error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'acorn-globals'.
    error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'acorn-walk'.
```

I also get this error for every test file I have.

Do you know where this can be from ? It was working well a few days ago...

Here are a few config files that can help :

For Typescript :

```
//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "lib": ["es2015"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*",
    "./src/**/*.test.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules"
  ]
}
```

For Babel :

```
//.babelrc
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-typescript", "@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

For Jest :

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
};
```

And my dependencies :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/es6-promise": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.10",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.188.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "express-fileupload": "^0.4.0",
    "express-winston": "^2.6.0",
    "helmet": "^3.9.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "mysql": "^2.15.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.3.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.3",
    "winston": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.9",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.1.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.1",
    "ts-jest": "^23.10.5",
    "typescript": "^3.1.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are using `typeRoots` correctly. This may solve your problem, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html the default is to use `node_modules/@types`.

Comment: Honestly you can probably take out the typeRoots declaration as I think the default will work fine.